# How to fix this issue "PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to private PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::__construct() from scope"

Tags: laravel-5, lumen

I am facing below mentioned issue when executing the command "**phpunit**" in Lumen:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to private PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::__construct() from scope PHPUnit\TextUI\TestSuiteMapper in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestSuiteMapper.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(390): PHPUnit\TextUI\TestSuiteMapper->map()
#1 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(111): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->handleArguments()
#2 /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php(96): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command->run()
#3 /usr/bin/phpunit(73): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#4 {main}
Next PHPUnit\TextUI\RuntimeException: Call to private PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::__construct() from scope PHPUnit\TextUI\TestSuiteMapper in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:98
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/bin/phpunit(73): PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()
#1 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php on line 98
```